# Trying to send one message via MQTT and sleep for 5 seconds

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, mqtt, sensors

I am currently trying to send a message via MQTT protocol which works. I am using a raspberry Pi and a vibration sensor as a means to trigger the sending of the message. At the start I would touch the sensor and it would send loads of messages at once which is what I dont want to happen. so I tried to make it sleep for 5 seconds after it detects vibration. But now it detects one vibration and then wont detect another one but doesnt stop the running of the file. the only way i can get it to detect the vibration again is to run the file again. here is the two ways I tried:

```
import time
from grove.gpio import GPIO

import paho.mqtt.client as mqttClient


class GrovePiezoVibrationSensor(GPIO):
    def __init__(self, pin):
        super(GrovePiezoVibrationSensor, self).__init__(pin, GPIO.IN)
        self._on_detect = None

    @property
    def on_detect(self):
        return self._on_detect

    @on_detect.setter
    def on_detect(self, callback):
        if not callable(callback):
            return

        if self.on_event is None:
            self.on_event = self._handle_event

        self._on_detect = callback

    def _handle_event(self, pin, value):
        if value:
            if callable(self._on_detect):
                self._on_detect()
                time.sleep(5000)


Grove = GrovePiezoVibrationSensor
def on_connect(client, userdata, flags, rc):

    if rc == 0:

        print("Connected to broker")

        global Connected                #Use global variable
        Connected = True                #Signal connection

    else:

        print("Connection failed")

Connected = False   #global variable for the state of the connection

broker_address= "hairdresser.cloudmqtt.com"
port = 15767
user = "kprpjfue"
password = "1fIq2_CIwHZj"
client = mqttClient.Client("Python")               #create new instance
client.username_pw_set(user, password=password)    #set username and password
client.on_connect= on_connect
client.loop_start()

client.connect(broker_address, port=port)



def main():
    from grove.helper import SlotHelper
    sh = SlotHelper(SlotHelper.GPIO)
    pin = sh.argv2pin()

    pir = GrovePiezoVibrationSensor(pin)

    def callback():
        print('Detected.')
        value = 'detected'
        client.publish("sensor/Temp", value)

    pir.on_detect = callback
    while True:
        time.sleep(5000)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()


while Connected != True:    #Wait for connection
    time.sleep(0.1)
```

```
import time
from grove.gpio import GPIO

import paho.mqtt.client as mqttClient


class GrovePiezoVibrationSensor(GPIO):
    def __init__(self, pin):
        super(GrovePiezoVibrationSensor, self).__init__(pin, GPIO.IN)
        self._on_detect = None

    @property
    def on_detect(self):
        return self._on_detect

    @on_detect.setter
    def on_detect(self, callback):
        if not callable(callback):
            return

        if self.on_event is None:
            self.on_event = self._handle_event

        self._on_detect = callback

    def _handle_event(self, pin, value):
        if value:
            if callable(self._on_detect):
                self._on_detect()
                time.sleep(5000)


Grove = GrovePiezoVibrationSensor
def on_connect(client, userdata, flags, rc):

    if rc == 0:

        print("Connected to broker")

        global Connected                #Use global variable
        Connected = True                #Signal connection

    else:

        print("Connection failed")

Connected = False   #global variable for the state of the connection

broker_address= "hairdresser.cloudmqtt.com"
port = 15767
user = "kprpjfue"
password = "1fIq2_CIwHZj"
client = mqttClient.Client("Python")               #create new instance
client.username_pw_set(user, password=password)    #set username and password
client.on_connect= on_connect

client.connect(broker_address, port=port)



def main():
    from grove.helper import SlotHelper
    sh = SlotHelper(SlotHelper.GPIO)
    pin = sh.argv2pin()

    pir = GrovePiezoVibrationSensor(pin)

    def callback():
        print('Detected.')
        value = 'detected'
        client.publish("sensor/Temp", value)

    pir.on_detect = callback
    while True:
        time.sleep(5000)
        client.loop()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()


while Connected != True:    #Wait for connection
    time.sleep(0.1)
```

As you can see under the if callable in the handle event method I told I say time.sleep(5000). Am I putting this in the wrong place?

Comment: No, you should have one or the other. Either `client.loop_start()` or `client.loop()`, not both.

Comment: They both dont seem to work. I updated my question to make sure I am doing both of them right.

Comment: You need one or the other in order for your MQTT client to work properly, regardless of if the rest of the system is doing what you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have not started the MQTT client network loop so it will not be able receive messages or send a message large the the MTU.

You will also get disconnected after the keep alive period.

Add `client.loop_start()` before the call to `client.connect()`

or insert `client.loop()` after the `time.sleep(5000)` in the loop in main and it will be better to make it 1000 to the client loop runs at least once a second.

Adding sleeps in callbacks is normally a bad idea as it doesn't stop events from being triggered it just delays them, because they will just be queued up until the sleep times out.

You should set a flag on the first event just after sending the MQTT message which you can then expire using the While True loop in main. If a new event comes in while the flag is still set then you just don't send another MQTT message.

Comment: the first method of putting the `client.start_loop()` throws this error `client object has no attribute start_loop` and the other one just does the same thing where it only detects one vibration and carries on running

Comment: Sorry, typo it should be `loop_start()`

Comment: done that just there and it says Connected to broker cause of the  print statement  and then it just finishes running

Comment: The `client.loop()` needs to go with the after the `time.sleep(5000)` in the While True: loop in the main function

Comment: still the same where it keeps running but only detects the one vibration. It's ever since i added the `time.sleep(5000)` in handle event but i need that as it would send too much messages at once. Also, i edited my question with all the updates.

Comment: sorry about this but do you know of any examples on how to use flags as im quite new to python.

Comment: I can see its a boolean but dont really know how to implement it

Comment: somehow its working now with the sleep in the callback so ill mark this as complete